# type 5 error while using MonetDBLite or readr

Tags: r, dplyr, readr, r-dbi, monetdblite

I am trying to write 80GB csv file onto the MonetDB using MonetDBLite using the following code.

```
mtcars[1:12,] %>% write_csv("mtcars1_12.csv")
mtcars[13:32,] %>% write_csv("mtcars13_32.csv")

setwd("path") # please use your folder path

dbdir <- "path" # provide path where you want to create the MonetDB

con <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbdir)

f <- function(x, pos) dbWriteTable(conn=con, name="mtcars1", value= x, header = T, append = T)

read_csv_chunked("mtcars1_12.csv", DataFrameCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 10)
read_csv_chunked("mtcars13_32.csv", DataFrameCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 10)
```

Now, this mtcars data works perfectly fine, but my actual data with exactly the same code throws the following error.

```
Evaluation error: Failed to insert data: MALException:embedded:Could not convert column 2 var_abc to type 5.
```

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the above error using mtcars as I don't know what's causing it!

What is "convert column to type 5" issue and how can I fix this?

Comment: does it work without using chunked? whats the output of `str(x)` in `f`?

Comment: It works with and without using chunked with mtcars dataset, but unfortunately, I can't reproduce this error using mtcars as I don't know what's causing it!

Comment: Okay, please answer the second question.

Comment: Looks like it was the data type issue. I made the data types fixed across datafiles before writing them down to the database and it worked. Thanks!